# What is the expression for "Current Geodatabase" to be used in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have features in different geodatabases. When I process the features inside these geodatabases from Model Builder,and provide output names for them, I want them to be something like "CurrentGeodabaseName_%name%".

I want to know what is the expression for including Current Geodatabase Name in the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page is pretty helpful explaining the various inline model substitution variables: [Examples of inline model variable substitution](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Examples_of_inline_model_variable_substitution/002w0000005w000000/)

```
 %Data Workspace%
```

should resolve to the geodatabase name.